# Como inserir ano a ano em um gráfico de série temporal no ggplot?

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

Estou rodando o comando

ggplot(regulation, aes(regulation$year, regulation$rqe))
 +
geom_line() +

geom_point(colour = "blue")+

labs(title = "ESTIMADOR DA QUALIDADE REGULATÓRIA (1996-2017)",
       x = "ANO",
       y = "QUALIDADE REGULATÓRIA",
       caption = "Elaboração própria a partir de dados do Worldwilde Governance Indicators")
 e o gráfico sai da seguinte forma

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dados vão de 1996 a 2017 ano a ano mas só roda de cinco em cinco anos. Já tentei várias opções para transormar os dados mas nenhuma dá certo. Alguém saberia como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Considere plotar o ano como fator:

```
ggplot(regulation, aes(factor(regulation$year), regulation$rqe)) + ...
```